# jQuery if Clicked

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting the following if statement to work, could some please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
<a id='slink' class='trigger' href='#Sports'>Sport</a>
<a id='elink' class='trigger'  href='#Entertainment'>Entertainment</a >
<a id='mlink' class='trigger' href='#Military'>Military</a>
<a id='mocklink' class='trigger' href='#MockUp'>MockUps</a>



$('.trigger').on('click',function(){
  if ($(this).attr('id') = 'mocklink') {
 alert('hey');
});
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` and you have to use [comparison `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) instead of assignment `=`. Learn how to use the console to detect such errors, it makes things easier ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace, and you need to make the test in your `if` a boolean. Use the logical "equal" operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`):

```
$('.trigger').on('click',function(){
  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'mocklink') {
    alert('hey');
  }
});
```

Comment: I like having most comparisons as === though. But you're right